# AJAX login: check password, how to get it to work with md5

Tags: passwords, compare, md5

this is my code, it works, except for the passwords, how would I fix this? I know I should do something with md5 but I couldn't get found solutions to work with my code. I really need to make this right and safe, please assist

```
                //get the posted values
    $username=htmlspecialchars($_POST['user_name'],ENT_QUOTES);
    $password=htmlspecialchars($_POST['password'],ENT_QUOTES);

    $check_for_username = $mysqli->query("SELECT username FROM q4jli_users WHERE username='$username' AND password=MD5('$password')"); 
    if (mysqli_num_rows($check_for_username)) {     
        echo "yes";  

    } else {
        echo "no";                                                                           
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MD5 is outdated and no longer a sufficient method of password encryption.  You should investigate salted hashes using more modern encryption algorithims.

food for thought:
[bcrypt](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4781/do-any-security-experts-recommend-bcrypt-for-password-storage/6415#6415)

Comment: hello, I'm using joomla 2.5, they use indeed salted hashes (just found out). How would you modify my code to get this to work?

Comment: I agree with @Dave, MD5 algorithm is not considered safe anymore. Please go through the following link: http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php#faq.passwords.fasthash

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to make sure that a user's password is encrypted into the database with MD5.  If not, then you can use this code:

```
$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO q4jli_users (username, password) VALUES ('$username', MD5('$password'))");
```

Then, when seeing if a user enters the correct password, you need to encrypt it to MD5 and then run a query in the database:

```
$check_for_username = $mysqli->query("SELECT username FROM q4jli_users WHERE username='$username' AND password=MD5('$password')");
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer, I've updated my code but it still doesn't work. I just found out joomla 2.5 uses salted hashes, how would you approach this code now?